# Semantic UI React change style placeholder text CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic UI dropdowns in my React application to create dropdowns like the one here in their documentation: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-selection

The default text is set to "Select Friend", and by default the text is semi-transparent. I'm trying to figure out how to modify the style of this component so that the default text is no longer transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to know you that the default text is not semi-transparent.

There is a CSS property for that default text in `semantic.min.css` as follow.

```
.ui.default.dropdown:not(.button)>.text, .ui.dropdown:not(.button)>.default.text {
    color: rgba(191,191,191,.87);
}
```

You can override this CSS property by applying the following code in your custom CSS file.

```
.ui.default.dropdown:not(.button)>.text, .ui.dropdown:not(.button)>.default.text {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87) !important;
}
```